Look for string in part of the worksheet to delete rows
I have a template that is used by a test software to print a report. This software will include measurements and results and can run small macros.
My template includes all possible limits for a test, and depending on the standards used for the test I want to delete the limits not used.
I am trying to look for three strings (corresponds to EMC standards title) to see if I need to delete rows that are specific to one of those standards.
If I have 55015 in the standard list I keep all rows.
If I don't have 55015 and I have either 55032 or 55014 I delete two rows.
Sub Define_Limit()

If InStr(Range("E8:J9").Value, "*55015*") = 0 Then
If (InStr(Range("E8:J9").Value, "*55032*") = 1 Or InStr(Range("E8:J9").Value, "*55014*") = 0) Then

Cells(68, 2).EntireRow.Delete       'deleting the row with extra limits i.e. 9k-->150KHz
Cells(69, 2).EntireRow.Delete

Cells(100, 2).EntireRow.Insert
Cells(101, 2).EntireRow.Insert

End If
End If
End Sub

I also tried this:
If (((CountIf("E8:J9", "*55032*"),True,False) = True) Or (CountIf("E8:J9", "*55014*"),True,False) = True) Then
If (((CountIf("E8:J9", "*55015*"),True,False) = False)) Then
 
Cells(68, 2).EntireRow.Delete       'deleting the row with extra limits i.e. 9k-->150KHz
Cells(69, 2).EntireRow.Delete


If you delete a row the rows will be "renumbered".  Therefore delete from bottom to top sequence than the rows which are "in play" will not be renumbered.

The easiest way is to loop rows from the bottom up. Providing a multi cell range "value" (should be an array) to InStr looks weird to me ... don't know if that's a thing. Same for a bare CountIf instead of WorksheetFunction.CountIf - are you getting errors? In the good old days when I actually did this type of coding I found automating the Search (Find) was sometimes fastest ... but not the easiest if you are new to vba.

Good point on the row numbers, I will correct that.

I am getting errors indeed. I am very new to VBA yes. Not very familier with it. Whats the difference between CountIf and WorksheetFunction.CountIf ?

CountIf should throw an error as it is not a defined function; you need to qualify it to access where CountIf is stored within WorksheetFunction, so WorksheetFunction.CountIf.

In terms of efficiency, using a loop with a negative step is simple, but using Union() to collect the ranges to be deleted and deleting said range in a final step will be better for the system.

Posting this as a possible alternative solution:
Sub Define_Limit()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim testRange As Range, findRange1 As Range, findRange2 As Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set testRange = ws.Range("E8:J9")

With testRange

    Set findRange1 = .Find("55015", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not (findRange1 Is Nothing) Then Exit Sub
    
    Set findRange1 = .Find("55032", LookIn:=xlValues)
    Set findRange2 = .Find("55014", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If (Not (findRange1 Is Nothing)) Or (Not (findRange2 Is Nothing)) Then
    
        Cells(69, 2).EntireRow.Delete   'deleting the row with extra limits i.e. 9k-->150KHz
        Cells(68, 2).EntireRow.Delete
        
        Cells(100, 2).EntireRow.Insert
        Cells(101, 2).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
    
End With

End Sub

